# ElasticSearch multiple AND/OR query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a schema like below -

```
{
    "errorCode": "e015",
    "errorDescription": "Description e015",
    "storeId": "71102",
    "businessFunction": "PriceFeedIntegration",
    "createdDate": "2021-02-20T09:17:04.004",
    "readBy": [
        {
            "userId": "scha3055"
        },
    {
            "userId": "abcd1234"
        }

    ]
}
```

I'm trying to search combination of "errorCode","storeId","businessFunction" with a date range like below -

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "errorCode": [
                            "e015",
                            "e020",
                            "e022"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "storeId": [
                            "71102",
                            "71103"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                
                {
                    "range": {
                        "createdDate": {
                            "gte": "2021-02-16T09:17:04.000",
                            "lte": "2021-02-22T00:00:00.005"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But when I add another condition with "businessFunction" the query does not work.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "errorCode": [
                            "e015",
                            "e020",
                            "e022"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "storeId": [
                            "71102",
                            "71103"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "errorDescription": [
                            "Description e020",
                            "71103"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "createdDate": {
                            "gte": "2021-02-16T09:17:04.000",
                            "lte": "2021-02-22T00:00:00.005"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing in the query? When I add the third "terms" cndition , the query does not work. Please suggest or let me know any alternate way.

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your index?

Comment: Are you sure that there is data in your index that matches all the 4 conditions since you are using a must clause? How many records returned from your 1st query would pass the newly added query? And, you are not querying businessFunction in any of the queries you mentioned.

Comment: Ya..it matches the record. I am just doing for testing, don't have much data now. 2 records coming out from first query.sorry for the typo.It's same with erroDescription field as well.For businessFunction I used below - {
          "terms": {
            "businessFunction.keyword": [
              "PriceFeedIntegration",
              "PriceFeedIntegration22"
            ]
          }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you are searching for "Description e020"  but in your example you stored "Description **e015**".

Short answer, I hope that's right for you:

"Description e015" will have been indexed as the two terms ["description","e015"].

use **match_phrase** instead of **terms**

```
 ...
 {
          "match_phrase": {
            "errorDescription": "Description e015"
          }
},
{
          "range": {
            "createdDate": {
              "gte": "2021-02-16T09:17:04.000",
              "lte": "2021-02-22T00:00:00.005"
            }
          }
}
....
```

Without knowing your mapping, I think that your errorDescription field its analyzed.

Other option not recommended:
If your field its analyzed and you require **match exact**, search in errorDescription.keyword

```
{
  "terms": {
    "errorDescription.keyword": [
      "Description e015"              
    ]
  }
}
```

UPDATE

### Long answer:

As I mentioned previously maybe, your field value was analyzed, then converted from "PriceFeedIntegration2" to pricefeedintegration2.

2 options

- Search by your field.keyword aka businessFunction.keyword
- Change your field mapping to not analyzed. Then you can get results just as you expect using terms.

#### Option: 1

It's the easy way, if you never run full text searches on that field, better not use as default. If it does not matter, use this option, it is the simplest.

Check your businessFunction.keyword field (created by default if you dont specify mapping)

Indexing data without mapping on **my000001** index

```
curl -X "POST"  "http://localhost:9200/my000001/_doc" \
-H "Content-type: application/json" \
-d $'
{  
     "errorCode": "e015",
    "errorDescription": "Description e015",
    "storeId": "71102",
    "businessFunction": "PriceFeedIntegration",
    "createdDate": "2021-02-20T09:17:04.004"
   
}'
```

Check

```
curl -X "GET" "localhost:9200/my000001/_analyze" \
-H "Content-type: application/json" \
-d $'{
  "field": "businessFunction.keyword",
  "text": "PriceFeedIntegration"
}'
```

Result:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "PriceFeedIntegration",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 20,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Get the results using businessFunction.keyword

```
curl -X "GET" "localhost:9200/my000001/_search" \
-H "Content-type: application/json" \
-d $'{
  "query": {

    "bool": {
      
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "errorCode": [
              "e015",
              "e020",
              "e022"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "storeId": [
              "71102",
              "71103"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "businessFunction.keyword": [
              "PriceFeedIntegration2",
              "PriceFeedIntegration"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "createdDate": {
              "gte": "2021-02-16T09:17:04.000",
              "lte": "2021-02-22T00:00:00.005"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}' | jq
```

Why isn't recommended as default option?

> "The default dynamic string mappings will index string fields both as
> text and keyword. This is wasteful if you only need one of them."

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-disk-usage.html

#### Option 2

Run on **my000001** index

```
curl -X "GET" "localhost:9200/my000001/_analyze" \
-H "Content-type: application/json" \
-d $'{
  "field": "businessFunction",
  "text": "PriceFeedIntegration"
}'
```

You can see, that your field value was analyzed(tokenized, lowercase, and others modifications depending of the analyzer and the value provided)
Results:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "pricefeedintegration",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 20,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

That is the reason why your search doesn't return results.

"PriceFeedIntegration" doesn't match with "pricefeedintegration"

> "The problem isn’t with the term query; it is with the way the data
> has been indexed."

Your businessFunction field value was analyzed.

If you require find(search/filter) by exact values, maybe you need to change your "businessFunction" field mapping to not_analyzed.

Change your mapping require delete your index and create again providing the required mapping.

If you try to change the mapping of an existing index you will get an "resource_already_exists_exception" error.

Here is the background that you need to know in order to solve your problem:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_finding_exact_values.html#_finding_exact_values

Create a Mapping on a new **my000005** index

```
curl -X "PUT" "localhost:9200/my000005" \
-H "Content-type: application/json" \
-d $'{

    "mappings" : {      
            "properties" : {
                "businessFunction" : {
                    "type" : "keyword"                    
                },
                "errorDescription" : {
                    "type" : "text"                    
                },
                 "errorCode" : {
                    "type" : "keyword"                    
                },
                 "createdDate" : {
                    "type" : "date"                    
                },
                "storeId": {
                    "type" : "keyword"                    
                }
            }
        }
}'
```

Indexing data

```
curl -X "POST"  "http://localhost:9200/my000005/_doc" \
-H "Content-type: application/json" \
-d $'
{  
     "errorCode": "e015",
    "errorDescription": "Description e015",
    "storeId": "71102",
    "businessFunction": "PriceFeedIntegration",
    "createdDate": "2021-02-20T09:17:04.004"
   
}'
```

Get the results, that you expect using terms businessFunction

```
curl -X "GET" "localhost:9200/my000005/_search" \
-H "Content-type: application/json" \
-d $'{
  "query": {

    "bool": {
      
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "errorCode": [
              "e015",
              "e020",
              "e022"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "storeId": [
              "71102",
              "71103"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "businessFunction": [
              "PriceFeedIntegration2",
              "PriceFeedIntegration"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "createdDate": {
              "gte": "2021-02-16T09:17:04.000",
              "lte": "2021-02-22T00:00:00.005"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}' | jq
```

This answer is based on what I think is your mapping and your needs.

In the future share your mapping and your ES version,  in order to get a better answer from the community.

```
curl -X "GET" "localhost:9200/yourindex/_mappings"
```

Please read this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_finding_exact_values.html#_finding_exact_values
and this https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings

Comment: Thanks Jugan.for your reply. I have given just an example for the data.I understand with your explanation issue with two terams. However, I am facing same issue with single string term with "businessFunction" attribute if I use -"terms": {
            "businessFunction": [
              "PriceFeedIntegration",
              "PriceFeedIntegration22"
            ]
          }  Also, for using 'keyworrd' why that approach is not recommended?

Comment: That's the issue. Thanks a lot Juan for your detailed explanation and help.:)